# Extremely weird OpenSSH messages

Tags: windows, ssh, freesshd

I'm trying to get public key authentication working with freesshd on a Windows server. I'm using OpenSSH to log in.

However, I get this weird error in OpenSSH:

```
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/ithisa/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 7b:1c:53:e7:80:2b:08:b5:96:e0:08:a1:df:6f:79:df
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: DSA 7b:1c:53:e7:80:2b:08:b5:96:e0:08:a1:df:6f:79:df
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ithisa/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ithisa/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@host's password:
```

As you see, the server "accepted" my DSA key, but then still somehow silently failed the authentication. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does user ithisa exist?
seems like OpenSSH is looking for ithisa pkey for key-authentication, and then it fails seen id_ecdsa doesn't exist for ithisa.

Comment: I'm passing `-l user` to the server, not logging as `ithisa`. Does this matter? I set up the key name as `user` for freesshd.

Also, the read for .ssh/id_dsa does succeed.

Comment: The server failed to log you in with that key for some _other_ reason. Check the logs in the _server_ to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ithisa/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ithisa/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
```

Seems like it cannot find your private key. Make sure the private key exists on the system you are connecting *from*, and that the filename matches what is expected.

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem. SSH tried the nonexistent ECDSA key only after the existing DSA key failed.

Comment: So why is the ECDSA key non-existent? Something is telling SSH that it needs that key (perhaps the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote host?)